# installing theano "blas error"

Tags: python-3.x, theano, deep-learning, openblas

```
>>> import numpy # OK!
>>> import scipy # OK!
>>> import theano # warning
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Failed to import scipy.linalg.blas, and Theano
flag blas.ldflags is empty. Falling back on slower implementations for
dot(matrix, vector), dot(vector, matrix) and dot(vector, vector) (DLL load
failed: Belirtilen modül bulunamadı.)
>>>
```

When importing theano, python gives this warning.
I setup theano according to this link. http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html

Numpy and Scipy imports are OK. but i'm stuck with BLAS.?

I clone to my computer OpenBLAS from github. 
how i add blas to environment variables ( "path" ) ?

Comment: AFAIK yes you need to install OpenBLAS .-. On the official website there is a [link for the binaries for windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/)

Comment: What exactly means install ? i download it, but how i recognize to python?

Comment: It may be simpler to get Theano running in Anaconda on Windows. You can even get fast matrix operations using their MKL extensions but it's a commercial product (free for students).

Comment: thanks for help @DanielRenshaw, its work with anaconda.

Comment: but it gives another warning 
`WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.`

Comment: Make sure you've run `conda install libpython mingw`.

Comment: run this code 
`Solving Package metadata: ...
Errror: unsatisfiable package specifications
Generating hint
[ complete ] | #### 100% 
hint : the following packages conflict with each other: 
-libpython
-python 3.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have error from scipy.linalg.blas, try to install the package from
, to install scipy please make sure you have install

> numpy+mkl

You can find it on http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

---

The other problem you've mentioned is that g++ compiler isn't detected, theano requires g++ (Linux and Windows) in order to compile generated C code.
(just google it deep learning theano setup might help).

The tutorial part of installing MinGW:

1. In C:\ create file folder’s name called Program
2. Install MinGW under this file folder ”Program”
3. Install msys under the path included bin folder.
4. run `sh /postinstall/pi.sh` in mysy and the direction you've just install MinGW is supposed to be `C:/Program/mingw-w64/mingw64`(depend on the install direction)
5. follow the step on http://rosinality.ncity.net/doku.php?id=python:installing_theano and you might have your code works!